# Can class use mix-ins pattern when using MobX?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mixins, mobx

For example, using mix-ins to extends multiple utility classes, like this:

```js
import { autorun, makeObservable } from "mobx";

type GConstructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

interface HasLife {
  grow: () => void;
}

class Animal {
  age: number;

  constructor(age: number) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}

function addLife<TBase extends GConstructor<Animal>>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Jumpable extends Base {
    // this is wrong, mixins class cannot use constructor!
    constructor() {
      super();
      makeObservable(this, {
        age: observable,
        grow: action,
      });
    }
    grow() {
      this.age++;
    }
  };
}

class Dog extends addLife(Animal) implements HasLife {
  constructor(age: number) {
    super(age);
  }
}

const dog = new Dog(0);

autorun(() => {
  console.log(dog.age);
});

dog.grow();
```

The example I provided cannot run correctly because mixin classes cannot have constructors, but I would also like to mark the member methods as observable or action in the mixin classes.
What should I do?
or, What is the common approach within the mobx community for dealing with this problem using other methods?

Comment: regarding the code comment ... _"// this is wrong, mixins class cannot use constructor!"_ ... Why shouldn't this be possible? After all the entire pattern is based on pure inheritance. How about fixing the constructor's  type-annotation of `Jumpable` which gets ad-hoc created via a dynamic subclassing by the `addLife` factory-function ... `constructor(...args: any[]) { super(...args); makeObservable(this, { /* ... */ }); }`.